# how to checks if RabbitMQ server is alive using the REST API

Tags: rabbitmq

I am totally new to spring framework. I am trying to create a project where I can have the connectivity to the rabbitMq and I even before I publish the message, I want to check if the queues are alive or not. Is this possible to ping the queue to see if it is alive or not?

Comment: If you can establish a connection to RabbitMQ, then the server is alive.

Comment: What's this about Spring?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ have the [management API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html). You can use it to check the status of queue,exchange,binding.

If you are working on PHP. Then here is the [libarary](https://rabbitmq-management-api-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which can be used.